# numeric columns ignore decimal values in mariadb?

Tags: sum, mariadb, numeric

In mariadb or maybe others, decimal values in numeric type columns are not included in calculation. For example,

```
MariaDB [mydb]> create table test (a decimal(5,0),b double(5,0));
MariaDB [mydb]> insert into test values (1.5,1.5);
MariaDB [mydb]> insert into test values (1.5,1.5);
MariaDB [mydb]> select format(sum(a),3) from test;
+------------------+
| format(sum(a),3) |
+------------------+
| 4.000            |
+------------------+
MariaDB [mydb]> select sum(b) from test;
+--------+
| sum(b) |
+--------+
|      2 |
+--------+
```

Why don't they return "3" what I want?
And why are their returns different?

Answer (score 0):

The `(m,0)` says to *store* `0` decimal places.  So, `1.5` is rounded up (or down?) to `2` (or `1`?).

The `SUM()` function works on what is *stored*, and knows nothing about the original `1.5`.

`DECIMAL(5.0)` says to keep only 5 digits to the left of the decimal place, and none to the right.

`DOUBLE(5.0)` says even worse things; do not use it.  Use plain `DOUBLE`.

Comment: in excel, for example, although 3 decimals are shown, decimals as much as it has are stored and every calculation functions take into account all of those decimals. How can I handle mariadb if I want to calculate for very exact results including decimals as much as it has?

Comment: Use `DOUBLE` _without_ the `(m,n)` qualifier.  The point is that `DOUBLE(5,0)` says to truncate _before_ storing.

Comment: Thanks for help, that's what I want.